# The method is undefined for the type SharedPreferences

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I need a help with saving checkboxes in my application. Eclipse show me these problems:

-The method setChecked(boolean) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences

-The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){}) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences

-The method putBoolean(String, boolean) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.actionoverflow;

import com.example.actionoverflow.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences checkBoxDummy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    checkBoxDummy.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkBoxDummy", false));

    checkBoxDummy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

    SharedPreferences.putBoolean("checkBoxDummy", isChecked);
        }
    });



}
}
```

How can I solve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `checkBoxDummy` should be a `View` object (probably a `CheckBox`), not a `SharedPreferences` object.
2. Use `sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(...).commit()` to save the boolean.